# Confusion over the definition of cardinality

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

In Abbott's *Understanding Analysis*, he defines cardinality as follows:

The set $A$ has the same cardinality as $B$ if there exists
$f : A → B$ that is 1–1 and onto. In this case, we write $A ∼ B$.

Do we *need* a function to exist? I mean, can't you just say sets A and B are 1-1 and onto? I know that the definitions of 1-1 and onto describe functions, not sets. BUT, later he proves that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable and it just seems like an awful lot of trouble to provide a function for that example. And whether or not you can provide an explicit function seems like a moot point in deciding whether or not two sets have the same cardinality.

Comment: "can't you just say sets A and B are 1-1 and onto?" What does it mean to say that a pair of sets (as opposed to a function) is 1-1, or is onto? "And whether or not you can provide an explicit function seems like a moot point in deciding whether or not two sets have the same cardinality." What strategies do you envision *besides* finding bijections?

Comment: Saying two sets are "one to one and onto" makes no sense by itself. What it _means_ is that there is a function from one to the other that is one to one and onto. You can't do without the function. So to prove the rationals are countable you need such a function from the natural numbers. Whether you go to the trouble of describing it with a formula or just demonstrate it otherwise with a convincing argument is not the point.

Comment: You need the function to exist but you don't necessarily need to explicitly construct it.  One popular strategy is showing that each must have a cardinality less than or equal to the other by constructing two injections. Another is to show that each has the same cardinality as a common set.

Comment: Injectivity and surjectivity are properties of functions, not sets. It's like asking "What flavor  is the sky?", it's technically a sentence but it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: In fact , it is very difficult to find this function explicitely in general. I have never seen a concrete bijection between the naturals and the algebraic real numbers. Rather are properties used , for example the countability of the union of countable many countable sets to prove a countability.

Answer (score -5):

It isn't that we need a function to exist; rather, a bijection must exist because the sets are one-to-one and onto. The primary problem with just saying the cardinalities are the same is that it's hard to directly compare cardinalities for infinite sets, which is why our function definition works --- it allows us to put two sets into correspondence with each other.

Comment: See the above comments.  Saying that the *sets* are "one-to-one and onto" is an abuse of notation that needs to be discouraged.

Comment: Apologies - I assumed people reading have enough sense to understand the implied "with each other" there, but it seems this assumption is incorrect. The _sets_ are one-to-one and onto _with each other_ implies there exists a bijection that maps each _set_ to the other. Hopefully, that clarifies my answer to somebody who cannot infer what should be obvious from context.

Comment: "The sets are one-to-one and onto with each other implies there exists a bijection that maps each set to the other." This is false. A bijection is one-to-one and onto. There is no such concept as two sets being one-to-one and onto with each other. Not only is that not obvious, it betrays a lack of understanding.